# Error sending user selected rating to server and refreshing ratingbar with json response using Android Volley?

Tags: php, android, json

I have a RatingBar where the user can rate a product. When the user selects their rating, the app is supposed to send the rating to the server along with the username and product id. Then the server is supposed to calculate the average overall rating and return it as a response. The RatingBar is then supposed to refresh with the overall rating for that product. Unfortunately, when tested, the rating system doesn't work and the error that is produced doesn't make any sense or hint to an issue. I've tried the logcat in verbose, debug and error mode but still get the same result. I've tried retrieving/sending the "float rating" but that produced the same result. I also included a "toast" message onClick to confirm that the rating is being processed and it is. I have no idea what is going wrong here and would like to know if I have the system running correctly? If not, what can I do to ensure the system works correctly? I converted [this](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-rating-vote-and-listview-part-2.html) tutorial to use the Volley library but kept the PHP rating code the same.

**This is the logcat response**

```
    04-03 17:48:02.538 20253-20253/com.curtrostudios.testapp E/new_rating: Rating Update Error: null
    04-03 17:48:02.562 20253-20253/com.curtrostudios.testapp D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 10328 ms: [ ] http://localhost/testapp/updateRating.php 0x1b9800e3 NORMAL 8
```

**If I try this within the browser using the POST paramerters, I get a HTTP 500 error**

```
    http://localhost/demoapp/updateRating.php?pid=1&userid=1&ratingpnt=3
```

**This is my PHP code**

```
    <?

    //load and connect to MySQL database stuff
    require("config.php");

    // Check Duplicate
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM rating WHERE 1 AND ProductID = '".$_POST["pid"]."' 
    AND UserID = '".$_POST["userid"]."'  ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
    if($obResult)
    {
        $arr['StatusID'] = "0"; 
        $arr['Error'] = "Duplicate Vote!";  
        $arr['Rating'] = "0";   
        mysql_close($objConnect);

        echo json_encode($arr);
        exit();
    }

    /*** Insert rating ***/
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO rating (ProductID,UserID,RatingPoint) 
        VALUES (
            '".$_POST["pid"]."',
            '".$_POST["userid"]."',
            '".$_POST["ratingpnt"]."'
            ) ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

    /*** Update Rating Average ***/
    $strSQL = " UPDATE products SET
        prod_rating = (SELECT AVG(RatingPoint) FROM rating WHERE ProductID = '".$_POST["pid"]."')
        WHERE pid = '".$_POST["pid"]."' ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Return New Rating Point
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1 AND pid = '".$_POST["pid"]."'  ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    $obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
    if($obResult)
    {
        $arr['StatusID'] = "1"; 
        $arr['Error'] = ""; 
        $arr['Rating'] = $obResult["Rating"];   
    }

    /**
        $arr['StatusID'] // (0=Failed , 1=Complete)
        $arr['Error'] // Error Message
        $arr['Rating'] // New Rating Point
    */

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**This is my ratingbar**

```
    final String rating = intent.getStringExtra("rating");
prodRating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        prodRating.setNumStars(5);
        prodRating.setMax(5);
        prodRating.setStepSize(0.1f);
        prodRating.setRating(Float.valueOf(rating));
        prodRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float newRating, boolean fromUser) {
                    updateRating(pid, uid, ratingBar.getRating());
            }
        });
```

**This is the function to updateRating**

```
    public void updateRating(final String pid, final String userid,
                            final Float strNewRating) {

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_UPDATE_RATING, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(AppConfig.TAG_NR, "Update Rating Response: " + response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // rating successfully posted
                        String newRate = jObj.getString("prod_rating");

                        prodRating.setRating(Float.valueOf(newRate));
                        Log.d(AppConfig.TAG_NR, "New rating:" + newRate);


                    } else {
                        // Error updating rating. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(AppConfig.TAG_NR, "Rating Update Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("pid",pid);
                params.put("userid", userid);
                params.put("ratingpnt", Float.valueOf(strNewRating).toString());

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleyController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, AppConfig.TAG_NR);

    }
```

Comment: if it works, then yes it is the 'right' way

Comment: @Dagon The problem is that it is "NOT" working. As you can see in the logcat, the response is null. Also, when tried in the browser with the specified parameters, the response is null/error 500.

Comment: then a better subject line would help

Comment: @Dagon Apologies. Fixed title.

Comment: check in the php if the queries does not return false if they do u can try to get the error using fr2.php.net/mysql_error

Comment: @djodjo checked sql queries individually and separately, they all work without error.

Answer (score 0):

In php you expect sid while with volley. Your send pid. You probably have an error in the SQL queries and you should check logs for that.

Comment: Sorry, it is pid in the php script. That was a typo on my part when I posted the question. I'll fix that. :/

Comment: Just curious but if you're familiar with PHP, do you think I could get the result I wanted using PDO functions instead?